# Bounded derivative has a fixed point at [0,1].

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, derivatives

$f$ is differentiable at $[0,1]$, and $0 \le f'(x) \le 1$.

Show that there exists $x\in[0,1]$ such that $f'(x) = x$.

So far I've got that if $f'(0)=0$ || $f'(1)=1$ we are done. Otherwise, $f'(0) > 0$ and $f'(1) < 1$. The thing is that $f'$ is not necessarily continuous, therefore I cannot define a continuous $H(x) = f'(x) - x$
and use the Intermediate Value Theorem.

Comment: While $f^{\prime}$ is not necessarily continuous, it still has the intermediate value property: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darboux%27s_theorem_(analysis)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define $g(x)=f(x)-x^2/2$, which is a continuous function.

If $g$ is not injective, by Rolle's theorem, we get a point where its derivative is zero and we are done.

Assume $g$ is injective. Therefore it is strictly monotonic.

If $g$ is strictly decreasing, for $x<y$

$$f(x)-x^2/2>f(y)-y^2/2$$

$$-\frac{f(y)-f(x)}{y-x}> \frac{y+x}{2}$$

Therefore $-f'(x)\geq x$, which contradicts that $f'(x)\geq0$.

If $g$ is strictly increasing, $f'(x)-x=g'(x)\geq0$. We get that  $0=1-1\geq f'(1)-1\geq0$. Therefore $f'(1)=1$.

Comment: @carmichael561 mentioned Darboux's Theorem, I see that it can be used for $g'(x)$.